# Difference between VectorSize in word2Vec and numFeatures in TF-IDF

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, tf-idf

What is the difference between **vectorSize** in **Word2Vec** and **numFeatures** in **HashingTF**? I refer to class *Word2Vec* and *HashingTF* in pyspark:

**WORD2VEC**: class pyspark.ml.feature.Word2Vec(*, **vectorSize=100**, minCount=5, numPartitions=1, stepSize=0.025, maxIter=1, seed=None, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, windowSize=5, maxSentenceLength=1000)

**HashingTF**:  class pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF(*, **numFeatures=262144**, binary=False, inputCol=None, outputCol=None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both the dimensionality of the representation, but the values will be in different ranges and useful in different ways.

In `Word2Vec`, each word gets a vector of `vectorSize` dimensions - where each dimension is a floating-point number (rather than a whole number). The values will be both positive and negative, and essentially never zero. Thus all words have coordinates in a fuzzy 'cloud' of space around the origin point.

Thus a word2vec vector is considered a 'dense embedding' of the word: it represents the word into a smaller vector space ('embeds' it) in a way where every dimension varies and holds some of the info ('dense'). As a result, all (100 in your example) dimensions will be used to represent any one item (word).

In `HashingTF` (which probably stands for 'hashing term frequency' or 'hashing trick frequency'), a text document of many words gets a vector of `numFeatures` dimensions - where each dimension is a non-negative integer count of how many times certain words appear in the document.

By using a technique called the 'hashing trick', it ensures any word, whether seen before or not, is assigned (by a hash value) to one of a fixed-set of counting buckets. The value of each dimension in the vector is the count of the words assigned to one bucket. In typical cases, many if not nearly-all of the buckets will be empty – and thus have zero values in the corresponding dimensions.

Thus a `HashingTF` vector is considered a 'sparse embedding' of a document: it represents the document into a smaller vector sapce ('embeds' it) in a way where most dimensions often stay zero, but a small relevant subset of dimensions become nonzero ('sparse'). As a result, the (262,144 in your example) dimensions might only be represented by a short list of which dimensions are non-zero and their value.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I choose and set right parameter for numFeatures in hashingTF?

Comment: Do you have any reason to tink the default value of 262,144 (as shown in your question) wouldn't work OK for you? (The essence of the 'hashing trick' is that it is fairly tolerant to variation in the size of the vocabulary.)